# PostgreSQL : I want to Provide Schema-wise access to users where user should not be able to see other schema names, how can it be achieved?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have situation where I have to give schema wise access to users where the user should not even be able to see other schema names as well as its contents like tables. I have tried below queries :

```
create user potter with password 'potter';
create schema if not exists potter AUTHORIZATION potter;
set search_path to 'potter';
create table pottertable(id numeric);
grant SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON potter.pottertable to potter;
```

In this case when connected to the server (PostgreSQL 9.6 localhost) as new user using pgAdmin 4, the user is not able to SELECT other schema data but able to see other schema names as well as the tables inside it, which is what I am looking to prevent. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use case? Why do you want some users not even to see the that the other objects exist? To your question: I believe this would require selectively modifying access to objects in the **information_schema** schema, which you'd want to do very carefully.